# Combination with neighbor books

Tags: combinations

How many options there are to choose 5 books from 12 different books, that the books are not neighbors. There are 2 cases:
1. The order of the choosing is matter.
2. The order doesn't matter.

I really don't know where to start.

Comment: Write A for books you choose and B for books you don't. Then the 12 books look like this: ABABABABA, with another three B's inserted somewhere.

Comment: Then to follow on from @user49640 's great hint, figure out the number of ways that you can put the other three B's, and you're well on your way.

Comment: Is it (3 from 10)? But the Bs could be different eaxh tine

Comment: If you really don't know, it won't be too long to write down all the possibilities. While you're doing that you'll start to get ideas about how you can do it systematically. I'm sure that's how 99% of us learned to do these things originally. How many slots do you have in which to put the extra B's?

Comment: If I can see the way I will understand it

Comment: And I have 6 more slots for the Bs

Comment: 6^3 (3 Bs left)

Comment: You have six slots for the Bs. That's correct. **But** all that matters for determing where the A's are located is *how many* B's you put in each slot, not *which* B's. So the answer is not $6^3$.

Comment: (6-1+3) choose (6-1) = (8!)/(5!*3!)

Comment: Yes, that works.